# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'force/empApiInternal'

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, lwc-dev-server

I'm trying to implement Platform Events into my LWC - I'm following these docs: [lightning-emp-api docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation).

When I try and import the empApi into my LWC I get the following error: (NB, it only occurs in the local dev server, when I deploy to my sandbox it works perfectly fine)

`Could not load force/empApiInternal (imported by /Users/<me>/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/@salesforce/lwc-dev-server-dependencies/vendors/dependencies-224/lightning-pkg/src/lightning/empApi/empApi.js): ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'force/empApiInternal'`

---

My `import` :

`import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError, setDebugFlag, isEmpEnabled } from 'lightning/empApi';`

I know I could just constantly deploy to my org during development, but thats such a bad experience, I want to make sure it the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's the case. The EMP is a Salesforce-specific feature, so you can't use it in the lwc-oss standalone. You'll get better deployment performance if you use a Scratch Org, though (on average, anyways).

Comment: Can't win em' all ahah. Thank you for the quick answer !